# Python command(s) to find unique names in long list

Tags: python, bash, grep

I have a data file which lists dates (indicated by the line containing `.`) and names followed by a number:

```
2015.05.22
nameA 15
nameB 32
2015.05.20
nameA 2
nameC 26
```

This list file is quite long (~97k lines and growing daily) and I want to (quickly) get all unique names listed. In bash I can do:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v '\.' | sort -u | awk 'NF'
```

but I am using this data in Python and I wonder if there is a way of doing this same thing in Python. I can, obviously, simply call this shell command from the python script, but I'd rather learn the 'best practices' way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick which basically implements the same set of behaviours as your "Shell" script:

*Filter lines in a given file; Remove any line that contains a `.`; Get a unique set of this data; Print it*

**Example:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

lines = (line.strip() for line in open("foo.txt", "r"))
all_names = (line.split(" ", 1)[0] for line in lines if "." not in line)
unique_names = set(all_names)
print("\n".join(unique_names))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py 
nameC
nameB
nameA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `re`

```
>>> input_str = """
2015.05.22
nameA 15
nameB 32
2015.05.20
nameA 2
nameC 26
"""
>>> import re
>>> set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', input_str))
set(['nameB', 'nameC', 'nameA'])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in just one `awk` command:

```
$ awk 'NF && $1!~/\./ {a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i}' file
nameC
nameA
nameB
```

This checks those lines having some data and whose first field does not contain a dot. In such case, it stores the value in an array `a[]`, that is later printed.

In Python you could use a `set()` to store data and prevent duplicates:

```
for name in set([line.split()[0] for line in open('a') if line.split()[0] and "." not in line.split()[0]]):
    print name
```

Answer (score 0):

The more verbose way of doing it:

```
unique_results = set()

with open("my file.txt") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
         if "." not in line:
             name = line.split(" ")
             unique_results.add(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line code to achieve this (assume Python 2.x):

```
unique_names = {}.fromkeys([line.split()[0] for line in open("file.txt", "r") if "." not in line]).keys()
print unique_names
```

The output:

```
['nameB', 'nameC', 'nameA']
```

if you want to make the output like the shell does:

```
print "\n".join(unique_names)
```

The output:

```
nameB
nameC
nameA
```

If the order of the names doesn't matter, python is elegant, too.